# Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph represented by adjacency list

Tags: c, algorithm

I was implementing Dijkstra's algorithm on a weighted directed graph given by an adjacency list. While I get the distance being calculated correctly for nearly all vertices the very last vertex of the binary heap is causing some trouble. Another major issue is while I am making a node assign to an array of nodes the assignment isn't being executed, as when I printed the heap node values their distance were always INT_MAX. Please help me out!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

long long int m=0;

long long int parent(long long int i){
    return i/2;
} 
long long int left(long long int i){
    return (2*i);
}
long long int right(long long int i){
    return (2*i+1);
}

typedef struct edge{
    long long int src;
    long long int dest;
    long long int weight;
}edge;

typedef struct vertex{
    long long int id;
    long long int d;
    long long int pos;
}node;

void Decrease(node heap[],long long int i,node curr,node V[]){
    if(curr.d>heap[i].d) return;
    heap[i]=curr;
    while(i>=1 && heap[parent(i)].d>heap[i].d){
        V[i].pos=parent(i);
        V[parent(i)].pos=i;
        node temp=heap[parent(i)];
        heap[parent(i)]=heap[i];
        heap[i]=temp;
        i=parent(i);
    }
}

void heapify(node heap[],long long int i){
    long long int l=left(i);
    long long int r=right(i);
    long long int lowest;
    if(r<=m && heap[i].d<heap[r].d){
        lowest=r;
    }
    else lowest=i;
    if(l<=m && heap[l].d<heap[lowest].d){
        lowest=l;
    }

    if(lowest!=i){
        node temp=heap[lowest];
        heap[lowest]=heap[i];
        heap[i]=temp;
    }
}

node Extract(node heap[]){
     node min=heap[1];
     heap[1]=heap[m];
     m=m-1;
     heapify(heap,1);
     return min;
}

void Insert(node heap[],node curr,node V[]){
    m=m+1;  
    heap[m].d=INT_MAX;
    Decrease(heap,m,curr,V);
}

int main() {long long int N,S,D,C1,C2,D1,D2,W1,W2,W3,i,j;
    scanf("%lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld %lld 
    %lld",&N,&S,&D,&C1,&C2,&D1,&D2,&W1,&W2,&W3);
    edge** adj;
    adj=(edge**)malloc(sizeof(edge*)*N);

    long long int* deg;
    deg=(long long int*)malloc(sizeof(long long int)*(N+1));
    deg[0]=0;

    for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
        deg[i]=(i*C2+i*i*D2)%(D);
        adj[i]=(edge*)malloc(sizeof(edge)*(deg[i]+1));
        for(j=1;j<=deg[i];j++){
            edge temp;
            temp.dest=(i*C1+j*D1)%(N);
            temp.dest=temp.dest+1;
            temp.weight=(i*W1+j*W2)%(W3);
            temp.src=i;
            adj[i][j]=temp;
        }
    }

    node* V;
    V=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)*(N+1));
    for(i=0;i<=N;i++){
        V[i].d=INT_MAX;
        V[i].id=i;
    }
    V[S].d=0;

    node* heap;
    heap=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)*(N));

    for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
        Insert(heap,V[i],V);
    }

    while(m>-1){
        node temp=Extract(heap);
        int i=temp.id;
        for(j=1;j<=deg[i];j++){
            edge w=adj[i][j];
            if(V[w.dest].d>V[i].d+w.weight){
                V[w.dest].d=V[i].d+w.weight;
                Decrease(heap,V[w.dest].pos,V[w.dest],V);
            }
        }
        /*for(long long int z=1;z<=m;z++){
           printf("%lld %lld   ",heap[z].id,heap[z].d);
        }*/
    }
    /*for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
        printf("%lld %lld\n",V[i].id,V[i].d);
    }*/
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: You have several loops that are suspicious on account of starting at index 1.  It's not clear to me yet whether these are wrong, but C arrays are indexed starting at 0.

Comment: For the same reason, the implementations of your `parent()`, `left()`, and `right()` functions are suspicious.

Comment: The first loop in `main` is definitely wrong since `i` reaches `N`, and is used as in index into `adj`. `adj` only has space for indexes `0` to `N-1`.

Comment: Your somewhat misnamed `heapify()` function does not serve the purpose to which you are trying to apply it.  At most, it moves the designated element down one level in the heap, but it needs to be prepared to move that element many levels down.  It will not be unusual to move it all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Made the necessary edits but it still calculates the distance wrong for only the last element to pop from the heap. Any more edit suggestions?